# JAX-RS bind MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON to java.util.Map

Tags: java, jax-rs

This might be too obvious but somehow I don't get it. Since the JSON payload is not relying to a schema, I need to parse it myself.

The service is receiving data formatted as JSON.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String index(final String data) {
    return data;
}
```

works as expected. I could parse and process the complex JSON object myself. But I'd rather invoke the service and have Jersey transform the JSON string into a `java.util.Map<String, Object>` for JSON objects and `java.util.Lists` for JSON arrays:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String index(final Map<String, Object> data) {
    // process the serialised types
    return "{\"status\":\"Ok\"}";
}
```

It is obvious that if I had structured data that I would implement a `class`, but the data does not reply on a specific schema, so I have to rely on collections.

Question: can I post JSON and have Jersey transforming the JSON in `Map<String, Object>` (`java.util.List` respectively)?

Comment: Can you specify your querstion a little bit more?

Comment: @Gulliva I added some more information.

Comment: Could somebody elaborate why my question was down voted?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to build a generic json service, which doesn't reply a specific schema and handles different json objcets as a Map or list? Did you try using jackson or any other json lib for this? I didn't vote you down....

Comment: That, that's what I need to implement. Down vote is gone. I check out Jackson for the data binding.